# McFarland or O.D of culture what to use and what is the difference?

Tags: bacterial-toxins

I am working on gram positive bacteria for which OD was reported and some reported mcfarland value. I am new to microbiology. i want to confirm the only thing that matters is cfu. please reply for what shoul I prefer
thank you.